# spree get total number of items in cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I want to display the total number of items that are currently in the User's cart on Spree Commerce. I tried to use @order.line_items.count but that does not work if multiple units of the same product are currently in the User's cart.

Please help me as I've seen a lot of stuff on the internet and can't figure this out.

ex. Cart containing the following:

SKU: ABCD QTY: 1
SKU: ACDF QTY: 2

Should return a total of: 3 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not worked much with `Spree`, but the documentation seems to mention `Order#item_count` which ought to return `The total value of line items’ quantity`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that.. I read Spree's documentation and did not find that info :)

Answer (score 1):

[On line 68](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/helpers/spree/frontend_helper.rb), Spree has a method called `simple_current_order` so use it as `<%= simple_current_order.item_count %>`

`simple_current_order.item_count` can also be used in your controller if you want to get fancy.